# Bot Emulator gets POST 500 directline.postActivity

Tags: botframework

I am trying to connect [Microsoft Bot Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) to my bot. Everything works fine when I host my bot locally but I hosted my bot at the following URL

https://hospitalbot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages

When I connect my bot using the Emulator and send a message it says the following (the log below)

```
[16:05:17]Emulator listening on http://localhost:51103
[16:05:17]ngrok not configured (only needed when connecting to remotely hosted bots)
[16:05:17]Connecting to bots hosted remotely
[16:05:17]Edit ngrok settings
[16:05:17]Error: The bot is remote, but the service URL is localhost. Without tunneling software you will not receive replies.
[16:05:17]Connecting to bots hosted remotely
[16:05:17]Edit ngrok settings
[16:05:17]Error: The bot is remote, but the service URL is localhost. Without tunneling software you will not receive replies.
[16:05:17]Connecting to bots hosted remotely
[16:05:17]Edit ngrok settings
[16:05:17]POST201directline.startConversation
[16:05:21]Error: The bot is remote, but the service URL is localhost. Without tunneling software you will not receive replies.
[16:05:21]Connecting to bots hosted remotely
[16:05:21]Edit ngrok settings
[16:05:21]->messagetest
[16:05:22]POST500directline.postActivity
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [16:05:17]Error: The bot is remote, but the service URL is localhost. Without tunneling software you will not receive replies.
>
> [16:05:17]Connecting to bots hosted remotely

Before you connect to a bot that is hosted remotely, please make sure you [installed and configured ngrok tunneling software](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#ngrok).

[image]